# fastboot commands time out but devices are visible

Tags: android, adb, fastboot, lineageos

I am trying to unlock the bootloader on my Aquarius X Pro 2. I am on Ubuntu and installed fastboot and adb and can connect via `adb shell` to the device or restart it into bootloader with `adb restart bootloader`. Also, I unlocked the bootloader in the developer options.

So when I am in the bootloader menu, I can see that the device is locked. I type `fastboot devices` and get this output: `XZ001532    fastboot`. So everything seems fine. But if I try any other command, like `fastboot flashing unlock_critical` or `fastboot oem device-info` nothing happens or I get a message like "waiting for device".

Anybody an idea what can be the problem here? I resetted the device several times, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after what felt years of debugging and asking for help, I was finally able to figure out the problem. I installed adb and fastboot from the outdated Ubuntu APT repos via the command line instead of downloading the current Google.zip per wiki install [guide link](https://wiki.lineageos.org/adb_fastboot_guide.html). With the proper tools, everything works now. I hope this helps somebody else to avoid the same mistake in the future.